# How to remove Firefox supplementary English spellchecking dictionaries?

Tags: linux, firefox, dictionary, spell-checking

Normally I have the US English spell-checking dictionary as default then I add  others that I need (French, Romanian, etc). But in Fedora 36 Firefox came with a lot of different English dictionaries that fill the menu.

[image]

`resource://gre/dictionaries/` shows only en-US, and `about:addons` only what I have added (French).

---

Edit after comment:

```
rpm -qa | grep spell | sort
hunspell-1.7.0-19.fc36.x86_64
hunspell-en-0.20140811.1-22.fc36.noarch
hunspell-en-GB-0.20140811.1-22.fc36.noarch
hunspell-en-US-0.20140811.1-22.fc36.noarch
hunspell-filesystem-1.7.0-19.fc36.x86_64
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of `rpm -qa | grep spell | sort`.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - please see edit

Comment: I wouldn't bother - they don't seem to be installed. Looks like a minor visual issue ;-) If you're annoyed however you can always file a bug report here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?classification=Fedora

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - what bothers me is the visual aspect, and now the fact that they are not installed :) I trust there is some file listing them that I could edit

Comment: I've always been using Firefox straight from Mozilla, so cannot relate :-) You can get it here: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/102.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/ works beautifully in Fedora, updates itself as soon as there are updates, you don't need to wait for Fedora maintainers to pick them up. It's also a little bit faster than Fedora's own build.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - I have found an answer and posted it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution on askfedora [HERE](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/remove-firefox-dictionaries/6234/2):

> If you go to about:config and type ‘spellchecker’, you’ll see there is
> a config entry called
>
> spellchecker.dictionary.path
>
> and it points to the directory /usr/share/myspell, where all the
> spell-check dictionaries are stored:
>
> ls -l /usr/share/myspell
>
> Note that most of them are just links.
>
> To get rid of all the many English entries on the pop-up menu, add
> /en_US to the end of the config entry so that it reads
>
> /usr/share/myspell/en_US
>
> That’ll hide all the dictionaries other than the US. Restart firefox
> after changing the config.
>
> You’ll note that the ‘Dictionaries’ section in Add-ons Manager shows
> only dictionaries you’ve added yourself and not those in the myspell
> directory.

[image]

[image]